# Valores escritos na memória stack não são "deletados" após o encerramento de uma função ou bloco de código?

Tags: c, stack

Tenho estudado o funcionamento das diferentes "regiões" de memória reservadas para um programa, em especial a memória stack.
No início eu achava que quando um bloco de código era "desempilhado" todas as suas variáveis locais eram apagadas, mas executando o código a seguir, notei o contrário:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f1()
{
    int x = 10, y = 14;    
    printf("&x = %p", &x);
    printf("\nx = %d", x);
    printf("\n&y = %p", &y);
    printf("\ny = %d", y);
}

void f2() {
    int x, y;
    printf("\n&x = %p", &x);
    printf("\nx = %d", x);
    printf("\n&y = %p", &y);
    printf("\ny = %d", y);
}

int main()
{
    f1();
    f2();
}
```

A main() faz uma chamada a f1() que contém em seu escopo local as variáveis "x" e "y" com valores inicializados, em seguida, o endereço de memória e o respectivo valor de cada variável é impresso. Até aí tudo bem.

Ao retornar e desalocar f1() é feito uma chamada a f2(), cujo funcionamento é igual, porém com as variáveis "x" e "y" não inicializadas. Ao imprimi-las, o resultado é esse:

```
&x = 0x7ffd089848fc
x = 10
&y = 0x7ffd089848f8
y = 14
&x = 0x7ffd089848fc
x = 10
&y = 0x7ffd089848f8
y = 14
```

O novo bloco empilhado para f2() não só usou os mesmos endereços de memória como também continuou a usar os valores da f1(). Portanto, cheguei a conclusão que valores alocados na stack não são apagados, continuam lá. Apenas o ponteiro da stack que se movimenta representando a alocação e desalocação de blocos. Está correto?

Em blocos com cláusulas condicionais o comportamento é semelhante:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    if (1) {
        int x = 10;
        int y = 14;
        printf("\n&x = %p", &x);
        printf("\n&y = %p", &y);
        printf("\nx = %d", x);
        printf("\ny = %d", y);
    }

    int x;
    int y;
    printf("\n&x = %p", &x);
    printf("\n&y = %p", &y);
    printf("\nx = %d", x);
    printf("\ny = %d", y);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Isso só ocorre com variáveis de mesmo tipo, é claro. Se na f2() as variáveis fossem, por exemplo, double, os valores seriam diferentes.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Olá, poderia colocar o seu código dentro da pergunta, de forma textual? Não é necessário remover a imagem, mas é importante ter as partes essenciais do seu código fonte no corpo da pergunta. Aprenda porque não é legal colocar imagens em perguntas [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7817/103217). Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar e executar o seu código. Imagens não desempenham bem nos mecanismos de busca pelo fato do conteúdo não poder ser indexado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considera-se como base o código seguinte, que também se encontra [aqui](https://godbolt.org/z/8sKT5GocP) (apenas foi reduzido o código original, porém mantendo-se a lógica).

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f1()
{
    int x;
    x = 10;
    printf("&x = %p", &x);
    printf("\nx = %d", x);
}

void f2() {
    int y;
    printf("\n&y = %p", &y);
    printf("\ny = %d", y);
}

int main()
{
    f1();
    f2();
}
```

Resultado:

```
&x = 0x7fff3b3a71fc
x = 10
&y = 0x7fff3b3a71fc
y = 10
```

**Alocar** significa reservar uma região de memória para uso e **desalocar** é liberar uma região de memória para uso. É importante atentar que desalocar não implica alterar/resetar/zerar o valor que está na região, mas simplesmente indica que a região está novamente disponível para uso.

Portanto, após a região de memória ter sido desalocada, perde-se qualquer garantia em relação ao valor que está no endereço. Ele pode ser preservado, zerado, etc.

É isso que acontece no exemplo acima. Em `f1()` é declarada a variável `x` e inicializada com `10`. Em `f2()` é declarada a variável `y` e é alocada para ela a mesma região de memória onde estava o valor de `x`. E nesse endereço ainda se encontra o valor `10`. Não é coincidência a região de memória ser a mesma. O *stack pointer* (sp) indica onde o próximo item deve ser colocado na pilha e seu movimento é previsível (ver **complemento 1**) (mais detalhes podem ser encontrados [aqui](https://cs.gmu.edu/%7Ekauffman/cs222/stack-demo.html#coderef-main))

Essa questão também é discutida no Stack Overflow em inglês: [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope). O exemplo é com ponteiro, mas a lógica é a mesma.

Então, voltando à pergunta original:

> Cheguei a conclusão que valores alocados na stack não são apagados,
> continuam lá. Apenas o ponteiro da stack que se movimenta
> representando a alocação e desalocação de blocos.

Os valores podem ou não serem preservados. É um comportamento indefinido e qualquer coisa é possível. Na realidade, em uma das execuções do caso foi obtido  `y = -858993460`, ou seja, o valor foi perdido. Quanto ao *stack pointer*, de fato ele vai se deslocando indicando qual o endereço do último item alocado.

---

#### Complemento 01

É importante esclarecer que é possível prever o deslocamento do *stack pointer* analisando-se o código assembly associado ao código fonte. A partir do código fonte não é possível inferir tal movimento. Isso porque o mesmo código fonte compilado a partir de compiladores diferentes (ou compiladores iguais com graus de otimização diferentes) irão possivelmente gerar assembly diferentes e, portanto, possivelmente diferentes deslocamentos do *stack pointer*.

Testando-se o caso exemplo no Clang nota-se que sem otimização a região de memória associada às variáveis `x` e `y` é a mesma ([código](https://godbolt.org/z/1dsaqbs5P)). Entretanto, com otimização -O3 as regiões são diferentes ([código](https://godbolt.org/z/q7nM3Wz9v)). Portanto:

```
Sem Otimização
&x = 0x7fff9952c1cc    
&y = 0x7fff9952c1cc

Com Otimização (-O3)
&x = 0x7ffce18eaa70
&y = 0x7ffce18eaa74
```

Analisando-se o assembly nota-se que com otimização -O3 houve um *inline* das funções. Dessa forma, a variável `x` ainda estava no escopo quando foi declarada a variável `y`. Dessa forma, foi associada à variável `y` a região subsequente.

Interessantemente, o GCC com ou sem otimização não realiza *inline*, logo os endereços de memória associados às variáveis são os mesmos: [código sem otimização](https://godbolt.org/z/Tso9b9j1K) e [código com otimização](https://godbolt.org/z/sYP4EnWfa))

---

#### Análise do Caso Condicional

O caso condicional foi simplificado, porém mantendo-se a lógica. O código segue e também se encontra [aqui](https://godbolt.org/z/4h8M76rs4).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    if (1) {
        int x = 10;
        printf("\n&x = %p", &x);        
        printf("\nx = %d", x);        
    }

    int y;    
    printf("\n&y = %p", &y);
    printf("\ny = %d", y);    

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Primeiramente, se a alocação se dá na mesma região de memória depende do compilador e do grau de otimização (os valores das variáveis podem se alterar a cada execução):

- GCC sem otimização: **diferentes** regiões de memória (`x = 10`, `y = 0`)
- GCC com otimização -O3: região de memória **igual** (`x = 10`, `y = 10`)
- Clang sem otimização: **diferentes** regiões de memória (`x = 10`, `y = 32764`)
- Clang com otimização -O3: **diferentes** regiões de memória (`x = 10`, `y = 0`)
- TCC: **diferentes** regiões de memória (`x = 10`, `y = 0`)

O código pode ser simplificado para se restringir à questão do endereço de memória. Dessa forma, analisa-se o [assembly sem otimização](https://godbolt.org/z/3o99nWKf5) e o [assembly com otimização](https://godbolt.org/z/4zfbb5jfd) gerado pelo GCC.

No assembly sem otimização gerado pelo GCC, os endereços de memória são diferentes, o que se nota pelas instruções:

```
// Endereço de x
DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 10

// Endereço de y
rax, [rbp-4]
```

No assembly com otimização gerado pelo GCC, os endereços de memória são iguais, o que se nota pelas instruções:

```
// Endereço de x
DWORD PTR [rsp+12], 10

// Endereço de y
rsi, [rsp+12]
```

Portanto, apenas o GCC com otimização -O3 associou às variáveis `x` e `y` a mesma região de memória e, ainda, preservou, no teste realizado, o valor `10` que estava na região. Nos outros casos foram associadas regiões de memória diferentes e os valores também foram diferentes.